# Nine others of my kind stand next to me

Tags: riddle

One is dressed in the same colors as I.
The other eight are wearing something white.
All nine of them are wearing something red.
Four of them are wearing something blue.

Who/what am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am

> the flag of Germany (or Belgium)

The other nine are

> the flag of Belgium (or Germany)
> and the flags of Austria, Denmark, Italy, Switzerland,
> France, the United Kingdom, Luxembourg, and the Netherlands.

One is dressed in the same colors as I.

> The German and Belgian flags are the same colors; black, red, and yellow.

The other eight are wearing something white.

> The other eight flags all have some white in them.

All nine of them are wearing something red.

> This seems like a trick; all ***ten*** of them include red.

Four of them are wearing something blue.

> France, the United Kingdom, Luxembourg, and the Netherlands
> all have flags that are red, white, and blue.

I could have chosen other

> countries

with these properties; I just randomly cherry-picked four of each group.